# Android AppAuth library signout redirection not working with Azure AD

Tags: android, azure, appauth

Configuration
App name: AppAuth Demo App
Version: 'net.openid:appauth:0.11.1'
Integration: Android native java
Identity provider: Azure AD

Description:
I am working on integrating the Android App with the Microsoft Azure AD for user authentication and as part this effort struck with sign out redirection. The code used my application is almost as the AppAuth Demo app code.

For simplicity of debugging the problem, I started using AppAuth Demo (Android Native Java) app to test and debug the redirection issue of sign out user from Microsoft Azure AD. The signin functionality is working as expected and after successful signin AppAuth library redirects to URI provided in the app. When user clicks on signout, the Microsoft Azure AD dispalys "You signed out of your account. It's a good idead to close all bwoser windows" , but not automatically redirecting to the end session redirect uri configured in the demo app (appauth.demo-app.io://oauth2redirect). Same redirect URIs are used in redirect_uri and end_session_redirect_uri as shown below:

{
"client_id": "a1a3cf2f-f979-3b9f-bbfb-121743895b45",
"redirect_uri": "net.openid.appauthdemo://oauth2redirect",
"end_session_redirect_uri": "net.openid.appauthdemo://oauth2redirect",
"authorization_scope": "openid email profile",
"discovery_uri": "",
"authorization_endpoint_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
"token_endpoint_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/oauth2/v2.0/token",
"registration_endpoint_uri": "",
"user_info_endpoint_uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo",
"end_session_endpoint":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/oauth2/v2.0/logout",
"https_required": true
}

When I debuuged the code, on sign out the AppAuth demo app sends the below request to Azure AD:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>/oauth2/v2.0/logout?id_token_hint=<>&state=TsKARQi5-HtTtVWanpsOIg&post_logout_redirect_uri=net.openid.appauthdemo%3A%2F%2Foauth2redirect

I am struggling with this issue for multiple days, but not able to find any solution to resolve this poblem. I am unable to identify the whether its the AppAuth library issue or Azure AD issue, someone's help is much appreaciated.

Thank you very much in advance.